# Problems implementing Adwhirl

Tags: android

I´m novice programming with Android. Somebody knows how to implement Adwhirl in Android app? I have see Adwhirl´s web page but I don´t know how to do this. Somebody knows a simple manual to do this or has a code examples? I need help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the [information on adwhirl article](https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/android/AdWhirlAndroidSDKSetup.html) or you can follow this way( which I was used for myself...)

In manifest add these permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

In on Create

```
LinearLayout adLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.XXXX);
        final int DIP_WIDTH = 320;
        final int DIP_HEIGHT = 52;
        final float DENSITY = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int scaledWidth = (int) (DENSITY * DIP_WIDTH + 0.5f);
        int scaledHeight = (int) (DENSITY * DIP_HEIGHT + 0.5f);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                scaledWidth, scaledHeight);

        AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout1 = new AdWhirlLayout(this,AdWhirlKey);
             if(adTest)//place adTest true while testing ..false while release....
            AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(true);     adLayout1.addView(adWhirlLayout1, adWhirlLayoutParams);
```

Note: Make sure to add the manifest items of these adnetworks(which you want to use like admob,inmobi..etc) in the Application's manifest.